# My .jar file generated from my Android Studio Project doesn't work after including gifs? Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, libgdx

I used Android Studio to develop my first project with libgdx. To generate my .jar i simply go terminal (on Android Studio) and write "gradlew desktop:dist". All works nice until this moment.

When i open my .jar that was generated by this command the program opens normally but when i click "play" the program exits.

Notes:
This has stated to happen when i included .gif images on my project.
The project works correctly on Android Studio and on my smartphone (it is a game for desktop and mobile version).

The problem is just on my .jar file generated.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the error log ?

Comment: That is no error log. The .jar simply exits. Can you tell how i see that error log?

Comment: Run with cmd, that will show error log ?

Comment: http://pho.to/AjKjB

Comment: @mljistcart Do not use external services. Edit your question instead and add the error message as text (not as image). Regarding your problem: You have the problematic line: `GifDecoder.java` line 596. Look at it what can be null and trace it back what call failed.